# Creating Summary table using countif and lookup

Tags: excel

I've had a bit of a mind blank with this so out of desperation I'm asking for your help.

I have the following set of data in Excel:

```
DE     | COMPLETE
FR     | NOT STARTED
UK/INT | NOT STARTED
DE     | COMPLETE
FR     | NOT STARTED
UK/INT | NOT STARTED
DE     | FAIL
FR     | NOT STARTED
UK/INT | NOT STARTED
```

The statuses will change depending on my project progress so I want to create an automated summary to count the statuses in the following table:

```
Territory | Fail | Not Started | Complete
France    |  0   |     3       |    0
Germany   |  1   |     0       |    2 
UK / Int  |  0   |     3       |    0
```

I know that it would be easier if I sort the table and create ranges for France, Germany and UK/INT then do a countif but i need to keep the format as it is.

How do I combine the lookup of the country with the count of the statuses?

Cheers!

Comment: Consider using a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a pivot table. [Here's the official link on how to create one.](https://support.office.com/en-IE/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why i didn't think of that as I use them all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Place your territories in **D2** through **D4** and your statuses in **E1** through **G1**.  Then in **E2** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$9=$D2)*($B$1:$B$9=E$1))
```

and copy both down and across:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!